# 2013/online auditing reports (content viewing never works)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, auditing, reports

In several places where I had to deal with SP on premise (2013) or online I always found out that the 'content viewing' report in the auditing reports is always null (giving me an error message, sorry something went wrong etc etc).

If I go to the audit settings, I can check boxes for some actions (Editing, checking in, moving, copying and deleting) and there is no viewing.

What is the trick to make this report work, I have been viewing pages and files so at least there should be my name on it, or there is no trick at all and simply it does not work. Specifically I am talking about the online version.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do content viewing reports in SharePoint Online, you must use the Compliance Center. The viewing option is not available in the SharePoint audit reports like on prem.

Another alternative is to use Google Analytics and track it separately. You'd need to create an app or use PowerShell to staple a custom action to your site. A nice option with this approach is that the data can instantly be consumed with Power BI and surfaced in nice graphs and charts with no real work.

Comment: but you guarantee me that on sp on premise that viewing report does work?

Comment: In the few times I used it on prem, yes it worked. This is not an option in SPO, it has to be done thru the Compliance Center.